# Getting nested data using GSON with Retrofit

Tags: java, rest, gson, retrofit

I'm using GSON with Retrofit to consume data from a RESTful API service. I want to access the nested data without having to create a wrapper class if possible. Below is what I'm looking to do.

From the API response below, I want to get **_links > self > href** link (specifically just the ID at the end).

[image: API Response]

I have a class through which I'm able to get rest of the data, here's a snippet

```
public class Fixture {


@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private Date date;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private MatchStatus status;
@SerializedName("matchday")
@Expose
private Integer matchday;
@SerializedName("homeTeamName")
@Expose
private String homeTeamName;
@SerializedName("awayTeamName")
@Expose
private String awayTeamName;
@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;

// getters and setters
}
```

Comment: What is the point not creating a wrapper class(es)? I assume that you can not change the service side so all the data is still coming whether you wanted it or not?

Comment: That's correct, all the data is being received. I thought there may be a better way of doing this as I want such a specific piece of data and not the rest of it. If I was to create a wrapper class, I assume I will need one for _links and then one for self in order to get what I want?

Comment: Quite so. Something like `String/URL href` in `Self`. `Self self` in `Links (_links)`